# Как создать букмарклеты (BOOKMARKLETS)

Tags: javascript

Как создать букмарклет? С чего начать? Дайте направление.

Comment: научиться писать на javascript, а потом загонять свой написанный код в онлайн обработчик, например https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/ ... всё!